# Subspaces stabilized by representations of $\mathrm O(9)$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

I am trying to figure out what representations of maximal subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_{n^2}$ stabilize one dimensional subspaces in $\mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Sym}^n(\Bbb C))$. More precisely, let the setup be as follows:

Let $H \leq \mathrm{GL}_{n^2}$ be a maximal subgroup. Given the following irreducible representation $$\mathrm{Sym}^n: \mathrm{GL}_{n^2} \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Sym}^n(\Bbb C))$$  where $\mathrm{Sym}^n(\Bbb C)$ corresponds to the Schur functor attached to the partition $(n)$ of $n$, we can represent $H$ in $\mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Sym}^n(\Bbb C))$ by mapping $H \to \mathrm{GL}_{n^2}$, and then $\mathrm{GL}_{n^2} \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Sym}^n(\Bbb C))$. It is known that the maximal subgroup $\mathrm{GL}_n \times \mathrm{GL}_n \leq \mathrm{GL}_{n^2}$ stabilizes a one-dimensional subspace spanned by $\det$ in $\mathrm{Sym}^n(\Bbb C)$ under the tensor product representation $\otimes: \mathrm{GL}_n \times \mathrm{GL}_n \to \mathrm{GL}_{n^2}$. My question follows below. I apologize if this is too specific a question, or improperly put.

#### My Question

I now want to go the other direction, and see if maximal subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_{n^2}$ necessarily stabilize one-dimensional subspaces under the $\mathrm{Sym}^n$ representation. To start, let $n = 3$, and let the maximal subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{3^2}$ be $\mathrm O(9)$, the orthogonal group. How can I detect stabilized subspaces? Will the weights of the representation let me detect if there are stabilized subspaces?

Note: I am also looking for good reading material to read up more on techniques for solving this problem, so a `reference-request` tag will be added. Thanks very much.